# Why is the web-page rendering well in IE11 developer tools IE8 user agent and document and messed up in "real" IE8?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-11

I am working a site:
http://dev.stooza.co.za

I try to support several browsers, including IE8. While I have developed it, I have tested using IE11 developer tools and switched user agent and document mode to IE8. It was more-or-less looking good, but now, someone, who has only IE8 from internet explorers told me that the site is messed up. Unfortunately he was right. My question is: why is the site rendering correctly in IE11 developer tools using IE8 as browser agent and browser mode and why is the design totally messed up in a real IE8 browser? Is there something wrong with the CSS? I did not see anything wrong with the JavaScript code.

Comment: Browser modes are not designed for testing purpose, but for supporting legacy web applications/websites until the developers update the code. For more info, have a look at [Craig Buckler's article at sitepoint.com](http://www.sitepoint.com/ie11-mysterious-missing-browser-modes/).

Comment: Yeah, I get the opposite effect. Real IE8 looks alright (as good as IE8 **can** look), but IE8 developer mode borks it.

Comment: The IE document modes are not the same as the old browser's rendering engines. They are to make old web pages work in new IE, not to make new pages look like old IE. If you want to test on an actual version of IE8, try BrowserStack http://www.browserstack.com or install WinXP and IE8 on a VM.

Comment: I work on the IE team, and just [blogged about Document Modes](http://sampsonblog.com/768/ie-doesnt-have-an-emulation-feature) a couple of days ago. You may find it helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the primary reasons your site looks worse in IE 8 is that it's loading in Quirks Mode. This is likely due to the fact you have a misplaced `<script>` tag above your doctype declaration:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var selectedVarsity = 0; 
    var searchText = "";
    var varName = "";
    var selectedCampus = "";
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
```

You'll need to move this into the `<head>` in order for it to be valid. No spaces or other characters can precede the doctype declaration.

Another observation is your use of Flexbox, something that wasn't supported in Internet Explorer until version 10. As such, Internet Explorer 8 won't understand how to properly layout your elements when you have a direct reliance upon modern practices like this.

It's important to note that Document Mode switching in modern version of Internet Explorer aren't meant to serve as emulation for older versions of Internet Explorer. [I recently blogged about this](http://sampsonblog.com/768/ie-doesnt-have-an-emulation-feature), comparing Document Modes to an A99 Aquata Breather (if you're into Star Wars).

If you wish to support Internet Explorer 8, you should do your development *in* Internet Explorer 8 rather than treating it as an after-thought. You can download a free IE 8 virtual machine from http://modern.ie, or access streaming virtual machines in your browser on http://browserstack.com.

To understand briefly what types of CSS support differences exist between IE 8 and IE 11, see this [side-by-side comparison](http://caniuse.com/#compare=ie%2B8%2Cie%2B11&compare_cats=CSS) courtesy of caniuse.com.

Comment: Thank you for the comments and answer. I will research the matter